# Train autoencoder without looping

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, autoencoder

I have some `data` that is of shape `10000 x 1440 x 8` where 10000 is the number of days, 1440 the number of minutes and 8 is the number of features.

For each day, ie. each submatrix of size `1440 x 8` I wish to train an autoencoder and extract the weights from the second layer, such that my output will be a matrix `output = 10000 x 8`

I can do this in a loop with

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras import regularizers, models, optimizers

data = np.random.random(size=(10000,1440,8))

def AE(y, epochs=100,learning_rate = 1e-4, regularization = 5e-4, epochs=3):
    input = Input(shape=(y.shape[1],))
    encoded = Dense(1, activation='relu',
                    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(regularization))(input)
    decoded = Dense(y.shape[1], activation='relu',
                    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(regularization))(encoded)
    autoencoder = models.Model(input, decoded)
    autoencoder.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate), loss='mean_squared_error')
    autoencoder.fit(y, y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=10, shuffle=False)
    (w1,b1,w2,b2)=autoencoder.get_weights()
    return (w1,b1,w2,b2)

lst = []
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    y = data[i]

    (_, _, w2, _) = AE(y)
    
    lst.append(w2[0])

output = np.array(lst)
```

However, this feels very stupid as surely I must be able to just pass the 3D `data` to the autoencoder and retrieve what I want. However, if I try modify the shape of input to be `input = Input(shape=(y.shape[1],y.shape[2]))`

I get an error

> ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 1440 and 8 for '{{node
> mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} =
> SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](model_778/dense_1558/Relu,
> IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [?,1440,1440], [?,1440,8].

Any pointers on how to get the shape right?

Comment: When you post the code, please ensure that all the variables that you are using are defined. The code doesn't have `regularization` etc defined.

Comment: Perhaps a RNN is more suitable for sequential data... (and in this case it automatically accept the correct data shape)

Comment: @Ananda fixed the function so everything is defined

Comment: @user202729 sounds interesting, do you have any more info

Answer (score 0):

Simply reshape your your data like so and call the function.

```
data = data.reshape(data.shape[0]*data.shape[1], -1)
(w1, b1, w2, b2) = AE(data)
print(w2.shape)
```

Your first layer of the NN is a Dense layer. You can only pass two dimensional data into it. One dimension will be batch size and the other dimension will be the feature vector. When you are using the data in the way you are using it, you are considering each data point independently. Which means that you can join the first two axes together and just pass it on to the NN. However, note that you would still need to modify the code so that you are not passing the entire dataset at once to the NN. You need to split the data into batches and loop over those before passing it on. And honestly, it's the same as what you are doing now. So your looping is not as bad as you think it is for what you are trying to do.

However, also note that you have a time series data and considering each datapoint as an independent point doesn't really make sense. You need an LSTM layer or something to learn the time series encoding.